# How do I install FTP for specific users/folders on CentOS 5.5?

Tags: centos, ftp

I want to grant FTP access to specific folders, with specific user/passes on CentOS 5.5.

Example of directories:
/var/www/html/userone
/var/www/html/usertwo

Yes security would be important, read and write access of course.

I haven't tried anything as it's a fresh new server, I don't even think FTP is installed, and I don't know how on CentOS.

Thank you!

Comment: What have you tried so far? Is this read-write access? Do you care at all about security for this? (Which is to say, do you have to use FTP?)

Comment: Yes security would be important, read and write access of course. I haven't tried anything as it's a fresh new server, I don't even think FTP is installed, and I don't know how on CentOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"yum install proftpd" should install the ftpd server.

I would STRONGLY suggest just using SCP/SFTP instead though - which is part of SSH. Pretty much every app and file transfer program (i.e. filezilla) already supports this anyhow. It will give you encryption - so if someone is sending files from their home, someone cannot snoop the passwords.

The easiest thing to do would be to change the owner/permission on the folders to just those specific users

chown -R user1 /path/to/user1/dir

chown -R user2 /path/to/user2/dir

Answer (score 0):

useradd  someuser -d  /var/www/html/userone  -s /bin/false
passwd  someuser     "and set 2 some pass"